# Fatal Error in Magento Command Line

Tags: error, magento2.3, cli, localhost, command-line

Trying to do a module check from the command line gets me a Fatal Error.

[image: m]

I'm using XAMPP to run Magento 2.3

[image]

Comment: check Compat.php file and look for line 1115 there might be something wrong in there.  Like a function with an infinite loop or etc

Comment: i dont see any issue with line 1115

 if (ParagonIE_Sodium_Core_Util::strlen($nonce) !== self::CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES) {
            throw new SodiumException('Argument 2 must be CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES long.');
        }

Comment: try to comment that function and rerun the command again

Comment: after commented. the error move to next line

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\xampp_\htdocs\sit2local\vendor\paragonie\sodium_compat\src\Compat.php on line 1118

Comment: did you get any errors in the log?

Comment: I mean aside from that error on your terminal?